# Getting 403 forbidden error in sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I want to upgrade version 13.10 to 14.04. This is output that I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My Ubuntu version is 13.10 Saucy.

Comment: A 403 error would be a problem with the remote web site...

Comment: Please, paste command that you typed, as well as your `sources.list` file.

Answer (score 19):

Opening the URL directly in a web browser gives this more informative error message

> The requested URL /ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages was not found on this server.

From this it's a short step to checking whether Saucy still exists. Looking at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ it's possible to see that it's not mainline, but that http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ suggests it should be available.

Looking more closely with a web browser shows that although http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages doesn't exist, the same file with a `.bz2` and `.gz` suffix does exist. Furthermore the same configuration exists for the current live distribution.

Searching for this scenario finds [Why can't apt find Packages file when compressed versions exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621032/why-cant-apt-find-packages-file-when-compressed-versions-exist) on AskUbuntu, which suggests that the solution is as follows:

> Turns out something was corrupt in my local apt repository. Resetting
>   it using
>
> ```
> sudo rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*
> ```
>
> fixed things.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
sed -i s/http/ftp/ /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
```

Comment: Had this error while trying to upgrade Debian 9 to 10. Using ftp sources instead of http or https indeed solved it for me today.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was our firewall. We adjust the rules, them solve!

Comment: Hello, I am having the same issue, is there a way to enable using ubuntu docker container along with having firewall and antivirus activated and still being able to work freely and securely?

Comment: hi @MinaAbdEl-Massih, of course! you need only to release the domains that you  will get packages. 

Get the domains:
```cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -Ev "^$|^#" | awk '{print $2}'```

now, you need release these domain or set as trust

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've had to add proxy configuration to my `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt.conf` file (I had to create the file first). Change the ports and/or delete the username/password if necessary:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxy-server-ip:8080/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxy-server-ip:8081/";
```

Or you can run apt-get like this:

```
HTTP_PROXY='http://username:password@proxy-server-ip:8080' apt-get install package-name
```

I've helped myself with this article [here](https://www.webservertalk.com/configure-proxy-on-ubuntu).

Comment: There is a copy-paste typo in the original article, I suppose. `HTTP_PROXY='http://user:pwd@proxy:port' apt-get install package-name`

Answer (score -2):

try adding the host below from /etc/hosts/ on the last line

```
91.189.92.201 ph.archive.ubuntu.com
```

first to check the address "E: Failed to fetch http://**ph.archive.ubuntu.com**/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxinerama/libxinerama1_1.1.3-1_i386.deb   403  Forbidden [IP: **202.90.159.172 80**]

change the address "ph.archive.ubuntu.com" from **202.90.159.172** to **91.189.92.201**

here is the command:

```
vi /etc/hosts/
.
.
.

91.189.92.201 ph.archive.ubuntu.com
```

then save it `:x!`

Comment: 91.189.92.201 (current rDNS urayuli.canonical.com) doesn't have the `saucy-security` package lists, so using it doesn't help in OP's case.

Answer (score -3):

Try changing the server your computer download the updates from.

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```